# can't get copyfile to work

Tags: c++, file-copying

i am just trying to use copyfile to copy a file, it is as simple as that but it wont work. i have googled it and looked at 20 links and they all say "[object.CopyFile ( source, destination[, overwrite] ) "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx)

The problem is i can't get it to copy the txt file for me, i have tryed running it as an admin but still does not work. also i need to put the source and destination as
 lpctstr (because it wont compile with out using Multi-Byte Character and my other code will not work unless i Use Unicode Character Set).

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 CopyFile("C:\\Somefolder\\file.txt","C:\\folder\\file.txt",0);
 return 0;
}
```

i am running windows 7, vc++ 2010, compiling as debug, sorry if i missed anything.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the function fails? Also the correct reference to the function is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - GetLastError() if the function fails will help you determine the error code.

Comment: The link you provide says that C++ does not support CopyFile.

Comment: @Martin, that's because the OP has inexplicably given us a link to the scripting host filesystem object (same function name, totally different everything else) rather than the actual C++ version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
CopyFile("C:\\Somefolder\\file.txt","C:\\folder\\file.txt",0);
```

with:

```
BOOL b = CopyFile("C:\\Somefolder\\file.txt","C:\\folder\\file.txt",0);
if (!b) {
    cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Okay " << endl;
}
```

That should tell you if and why it's failing. The error code, once you have it, can be looked up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

And if, as your comment indicates, you're getting `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, the *first* thing I'd be looking at is whether the paths `c:\somefolder` and `c:\folder` exist as well as the actual source file `c:\somefolder\file.txt`.

One special thing to keep in mind: `CopyFile` won't create the directory for the target file, it has to exist before you try to copy. There are numerous ways you can do this, such as with [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`CreateDirectoryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SHCreateDirectoryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Alternatively, put a breakpoint and add `$err,hr` to your watchlist.

Comment: @bob: does `C:\folder` exist? (destination directory). Also, does the source file exist?

Comment: @bob How did you get it to work? I'm having the same issue and both paths exist.

Comment: @SpencerRuport, are you getting `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` from `GetLastError()`?

Comment: @paxdiablo - Yes. :(

Comment: @Spencer, I'd suggest then posting your own question with enough detail/code to differentiate it from this one. You'll get more exposure that way.

Answer (score -1):

you have to check to close the file with fclose(FILE*) if you used fopen(...) or CloseHandle(HANDLE) if you used a HANDLE for the file (like hFile...)...
for me in C it works!

ANTARES (IT)